# Orbit camera implementation in OGRE

Tags: graphics, sdk, ogre

Since I am very new to Ogre3D, I only somehow managed to complete the designing features but finally got stuck with my camera implementation:

- implementing a 3rd person camera
- implementing an orbit camera (where the camera focuses (looks-at) at a point in the center of the room)

I just have the code for a normal camera.

```
void Assignment1::createCamera(void){
mCamera = mSceneMgr->createCamera("PlayerCam");  // create the camera
mCamera->setPosition(Ogre::Vector3(0,10,500)); // set its position, direction  
mCamera->lookAt(Ogre::Vector3(0,0,0));
mCamera->setNearClipDistance(5);                 // set the near clip distance
mCameraMan = new OgreBites::SdkCameraMan(mCamera);   // create a default camera controller
}
```

Could anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The OgreBites framework (which is used by the Ogre SampleBrowser), has examples for different options of camera handling combined in the [Ogre SdkCameraMan](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=SdkCameraMan). The actual code can be found in `SdkCameraMan.h` from the Ogre repository.

To switch the mode to orbit camera, just add the following line: `mCameraMan->setStyle(CS_ORBIT);`

Some general excerpts / pointers:

- For an orbit camera, you can use the inbuild Ogre feature for each camera, to specify a loot-at target: `mCamera->setAutoTracking(true, mTargetNode);`. Additionally you can also prevent yaw movements like this: `mCamera->setFixedYawAxis(true);`.
- For a 3rd person camera, you just need to create a child node of your character and move it back a bit and bind the camera to it. It will then follow your character around and should also inherits its rotation changes.